# PHP Native OS 'Remember Me'

Tags: php, session, browser, authentication, keychain

Sorry if the title was misleading. I want to know how to trigger the default OS password keeper when a user successfully logs in.

Example: I use Chrome in OSX, whenever I login somewhere I get the option for Chrome to save my login info, which stores the info in my keychain.

This is not a question about a 'remember me' checkbox for the login form, but rather how to get the browser to *ask* to save the info. Do I need to send a particular HTTP status code if the login was successful? Currently I'm storing session data once logged in, so the browser doesn't really see the change.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that browsers will ask if you have a field of type 'password'.

Comment: I think OP is referring to the OS keychain instead of the browser's own password database.

Comment: I'm already using an input with type 'password' and that isn't triggering it...

Answer (score 0):

There is probably some standard somewhere that says what the name of your username and password fields should be. I'll take a wild guess and say `username` and `password`, but because different browsers handle things differently, Google it. A good browser should be able to recognize the field pair and prompt the user if they want to store the info.

I doubt a browser will simply look for a field of type `password`, because there are plenty of times when a password field is used for other things (SSN numbers or PIN numbers, for example). I've never been prompted to save my "username and password" when I'm entering something like a SSN that happens to be in a `password` field.

Comment: I did some searching for this and couldn't find any specific answers. I checked a few sites that I know triggered and their fields weren't named a specific way. If I figure this out I'll post answer back here. Thanks for the suggestions though!